# Refactoring legacy java banking code

Tags: java, finance

Hey i have some legacy code i'm working on (It is open source so no problem in me sharing it!). I wanted to refactor some parts in the `extractResult` method since it got pretty repetitive. The `*.*.*` are extracted from XML, so there is not much to do. I realized that the creation of the Saldos and Values is pretty similar though that's why i extracted the code for its creation into respective methods (createSaldo and createValue). The only thing that doesn't match is the `info.reserved` field which is also a Saldo but doesn't take the infos from the same XML as the other Saldos (That is why the keys are different). You can check the old version of the code [here](https://github.com/adorsys/hbci4java-adorsys). The PR there is also from me, which includes changes for the UPD(). If you want to check the old version of the code take a look at GVSaldoReq.

How would you further refactor this? And thanks for any inputs!

```
protected void extractResults(HBCIMsgStatus msgstatus, String header, int idx) {
    HashMap<String, String> result = msgstatus.getData();
    GVRSaldoReq.Info info = new GVRSaldoReq.Info();

    info.konto = new Konto();
    info.konto.country = result.get(header + ".KTV.KIK.country");
    info.konto.blz = result.get(header + ".KTV.KIK.blz");
    info.konto.number = result.get(header + ".KTV.number");
    info.konto.subnumber = result.get(header + ".KTV.subnumber");
    info.konto.bic = result.get(header + ".KTV.bic");
    info.konto.iban = result.get(header + ".KTV.iban");
    info.konto.type = result.get(header + ".kontobez");
    info.konto.curr = result.get(header + ".curr");
    passport.fillAccountInfo(info.konto);

    Map<String, String> resultHeader = getByPrefix(result, header);
    info.ready = createSaldo(getByPrefix(resultHeader, "booked"));

    Map<String, String> pendingMap = getByPrefix(resultHeader, "pending");
    Optional.ofNullable(pendingMap.get("CreditDebit")).ifPresent(creditDebit -> 
    info.unready = createSaldo(pendingMap));

    info.kredit = createValue(getByPrefix(resultHeader, "kredit"), false);
    info.available = createValue(getByPrefix(resultHeader, "curr"), false);
    info.used = createValue(getByPrefix(resultHeader, "value"), false);

    retrieveReservedBalanceInfoFromUPD().ifPresent(accountDataInfo -> {
        Map<String, String> reservedBalanceInfo = getByPrefix(accountDataInfo, "Balance.VOR");
        Optional.ofNullable(reservedBalanceInfo.get("Amount")).ifPresent(
            amount -> {
                amount = amount.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");

                info.reserved = new Saldo();
                info.reserved.value = new Value(amount, reservedBalanceInfo.getOrDefault("Currency", "EUR"));

                Optional.ofNullable(reservedBalanceInfo.get("Date")).ifPresent(
                        date -> info.reserved.timestamp = HBCIUtils.string2DateISO(reservedBalanceInfo.get("Date"), "yyyyMMdd")
                );
            }
        );
    });

    ((GVRSaldoReq) (jobResult)).store(info);
}

private Value createValue(Map<String, String> data, boolean negative) {
    final var value = data.get("value");

    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    final var currency = data.get("curr");
    final var valueObj = new Value(value, currency);
    if (negative) {
        valueObj.setValue(valueObj.getBigDecimalValue().negate());
    }
    return valueObj;
}

private Saldo createSaldo(Map<String, String> data) {
    final Saldo saldo = new Saldo();
    saldo.value = createValue(getByPrefix(data, "BTG"), "D".equals(data.get("CreditDebit")));
    saldo.timestamp = HBCIUtils.strings2DateTimeISO(data.get("date"), data.get("time"));
    return saldo;
}

private static Map<String, String> getByPrefix(Map<String, String> data, String keyPrefix) {
    return data.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith(keyPrefix + "."))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().substring(keyPrefix.length() + 1), Map.Entry::getValue));
    }

private Optional<Map<String, String>> retrieveReservedBalanceInfoFromUPD() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(passport.getUPD().get("KInfo.accountdata")).map(accountData -> {
            final var reservedBalancePattern = Pattern.compile("(Balance\\.VOR\\..*?)=(.*?(?=;))");
            final var matcher = reservedBalancePattern.matcher(accountData);

            Map<String, String> reservedBalanceInfo = new HashMap<>();
            while (matcher.find()) {
                final var key = matcher.group(1);
                final var value = matcher.group(2);
                reservedBalanceInfo.put(key, value);
            }

            return reservedBalanceInfo;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: What are `passport` and `jobResult`, where do they come from?

Comment: You can check the link i posted in the OP. The passport is an object that contains a lot of different parameters for configuring the banking access. The jobResult is the result of the to be executed job (GVSaldoReqs response). You can check the code on GitHub, but i think knowing the exact details won't be necessary for a small-scale refactor. (I'm not planning on refactoring the complete application, only wanted to clean up the one class first, maybe we can generalise later :))

Answer (score 1):

***Small Issues***

Still saw an other point:

```
HashMap<String, String> result = msgstatus.getData();

private Konto configureKonto(String header, 
                         HashMap<String, String> result) {
```

Replace `HashMap` with `Map`. As the remainder: program against interfaces.
Then later you may change the implementation to LinkedHashMap (order by insertion), or SortedMap/TreeMap (order by key).

***XML Deserialisation***

This code maps XML to a Map, does some conversions, and produces objects like Konto.

Using **JAXB** with annotations is unproblematic to convert the XML to a java DOM (Document Object Model) which mirrors the XML.

It is sufficiently flexible to ignore undefined attributes and elements in XML, or have extra fields in java.

If you have a different (or no) object hierarchy, you can use inheritance:

```
<bar><foo/><foo/><foo/></bar>

@XmlElement("bar")
class Bar{
    ...
    List<Bar> foos;
}
@XmlElement("foo")
class Foo { }
```

as

```
@XmlElement("bar")
class Baz extends Bar {
    ...
    List<Foo> foos;
}
class Bar {
     ...
}
```

You should start simple though.

***Conversions***

Can be done too.

For amounts you use String converted to programmer's notation with a decimal point.

Immediately convert to `BigDecimal` with a `Locale.GERMANY`.

That would clean up things.

***How to implement JAXB***

Try it in a separate project, with simplified XML, and writing the java classes yourself. Gaining experience with List and Map fields, child classes, conversion and more.

Using Test Driven Development, you can jard-code your java DOM object hierarchy and write it back to XML for comparison.

That is fun.

Answer (score 0):

This are my thougths:

## Split  big methods

Your method `extractResults()` is rather long and already visually split up into sections doing different things.
Eg. there is a large block configuring a newly creates `Konto` object.
This could be moved to its own method:

```
  protected void extractResults(HBCIMsgStatus msgstatus, 
                              String header,
                                    int idx) {
  //..
      info.konto = configureKonto(header, result);
      passport.fillAccountInfo(info.konto);
  //..
}
  private Konto configureKonto(String header, 
                             HashMap<String, String> result) {
      Konto konto = new Konto();
      konto.country = result.get(header + ".KTV.KIK.country");
      konto.blz = result.get(header + ".KTV.KIK.blz");
      konto.number = result.get(header + ".KTV.number");
      konto.subnumber = result.get(header + ".KTV.subnumber");
      konto.bic = result.get(header + ".KTV.bic");
      konto.iban = result.get(header + ".KTV.iban");
      konto.type = result.get(header + ".kontobez");
      konto.curr = result.get(header + ".curr");
      return konto;
  }
```

This opens the opportunity to move this method into a new `KontoConfiguratior` class...

## Extract lambda blocks to methods

When your lambdas grow to blocks you should extract them to separate methods.
That makes the lambda itself easier to read:

```
  protected void extractResults(HBCIMsgStatus msgstatus, 
                              String header,
                                    int idx) {
  //..
      retrieveReservedBalanceInfoFromUPD().ifPresent(
              accountDataInfo -> processAccountData(accountDataInfo, info));
  //..
}

  private void processAccountData(Map<String, String> accountDataInfo, 
                                GVRSaldoReq.Info info) {
  //..
}
```

## Unitize similar tasks

At some points you use `Optional` to deal with possible `null` values.
You should do this all over your code in the same way.
When doing so (along with the first point) your method `createValue()` would look like this:

```
  private Value createValue(Map<String, String> data, boolean negative) {
      return Optional.of(data.get("value"))
              .map(value -> convertValue(value, data, negative))
              .orElseGet(null);
  }


  private Value convertValue(String value, 
                             Map<String, String> data,
                             boolean negative) {
  //..
  }
```

<sup>**Detour on `null`**: Returning literal `null` is a really bad idea. It is a potential cause for a `NullPointerException` in the code of someone else.
Usually it is done as an *error signal* and  throwing an *exception* would be more appropriate.
If it does not signal an error, a *neutral element* (a value of zero (0) in this case) might be a better choice to be returned.

But either way, this is a quite grievous design decision.</sup>

The same applies to the style of variable declaration.
Some of your local variables are declared `final` while others (including method parameters) are not although they also never change.
I admit, that I don't like the `var` key word but when you go for it you should consequently use that all over your code.

It's part of the boy scout rule that this stuff is consistent when you finished your refactoring, at least within the methods you touched.

## Read API docu to avoid complex solutions

In your `createValue()` method you check if the Value is negative to make it positive in that case.
Instead of introducing branching here you could simply apply the `abs()` method from the `BigDecimal` class:

```
private Value convertValue(String value, 
                           Map<String, String> data,
                           boolean negative) {
  final var currency = data.get("curr");
  final var valueObj = new Value(value, currency);
  valueObj.setValue(valueObj.getBigDecimalValue().abs());
  return valueObj;
}
```

This also makes the parameter `negative` obsolete.

---

**[update]**

> The flag is actually there to make the value negative, not to make the negative value positive. – Saltuk Kezer

In that case my prefered solution would be to modify the incoming String parameter `value` before passing it to the `Value` constructor like this:

```
final var sign = isNegative?"-":"";
final var valueObj = new Value( sign+value, currency);
```

omitting the access to the internal representation.

BTW: This access to the internal representation is a violation of the *encapsulation - information hiding* principle and an anti pattern called *feature envy*: you manipulate a property of the object from outside.

Comment: Sounds awesome! Thanks for the review. I will try to implement all your suggested changes from monday onwards :)
Regarding your last point with the negative flag. The flag is actually there to make the value negative, not to make the negative value positive. If the "negative" value is set to true, the amount becomes negative. Maybe the name is badly given then.